# Is it possible to turn an irobot roomba into a create

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

As irobot do not sell the create in Australia and will not ship to Australia I am considering buying a second hand roomba to convert to a create.

Is this possible, what models should be avoided and any advise?

Thanks